# SharePoint 2013: How to open specific view if the form authentication failed

Tags: sharepoint-addin, custom-form, forms-authentication

I developed a Custom Form and at the form workflow I sent an email to the director to approve or reject user's request via link that opens the Director view of the form

The form have 4 views: Employee, Director, IT and Access Denied View

Now when the director receive the email and open the link, the SharePoint asks for her username and password at the active directory.

I Wanna validated if the interned username is equal to the value of the field (Director username) of the form. If so, I wanna open the view and if NOT I wanna open anther view (Access Denied View).

How to do so ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have a directors list:

replace a link in the email to link to page with a script:

use client object model js (by SP.js)

```
function getViewByPermissions() {
    var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current()
    var list = clientContext.get_web(),get_lists().getByTitle("Directors");
    CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View>" +
                           "<Query>" +
                            "<Where>" +
                             "<Eq>" +
                              "<FieldRef Name='Name' />" +
                              "<Value Type='Text'>" + username + " </Value>" +
                             "</Eq>" +
                            "</Where>" +
                           "</Query>" +
                          "</View>");
    this.myList = list.getItems(camlQuery);
    clientContext.load(this.myList);
    clientContext.ExecuteQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed)
}

function onQuerySucceeded()
{
    var count = this.myList.get_count();
    if(count == undefined || count == 0)
       location.href = //Access Denied View
    else //if(count > 0)
        location.href = //Director View
}

function onQueryFailed()
{
    location.href = //Access Denied View
}


$(document).ready(function(){
   getViewByPermissions()
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your great help. Please help me in understanding your code. I never used  client object model js. Where should I store the script? what changes I need to do to your code to make it work?

Comment: Kindly check my comments. I need your help.

Comment: see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798388.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and examples:  [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163201.aspx#Anchor_7](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163201.aspx#Anchor_7), [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee537013.aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee537013.aspx)

Comment: I will try my best to understand your links, I didn't learn C sharp and this type of JS therefore, I couldn't understand your code.